# Extract r symbolic regression best model in java

Tags: java, r

I am calling R symbolic regression function from java by passing r script using Rengine. 
 As I try to extract the best model in Java I get null. I could tell by extracting another value(s$bestFitness) from the symbolic regression result that it is not null so it looks I am extracting the best model the wrong way.  As I see in this tutorial: http://www.studytrails.com/RJava-Eclipse-Plugin/Execute-R-From-Java.jsp how they extract the intercept from linear regression result using asVector().at[i].asDoubleArray()[j]. I thought the solution to my problem should look similar. I could not figure out why they did it this way so I could not map the solution to my problem. Any tips on extracting the best model would be very much appreciated.
Here is my code:

```
import org.rosuda.JRI.REXP;
import org.rosuda.JRI.RVector;
import org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine;
import org.rosuda.REngine.REXPMismatchException;
import org.rosuda.REngine.REngineException;
import org.rosuda.REngine.JRI.JRIEngine;
public class REn {

public static void main(String[] args) throws REngineException, REXPMismatchException {
    org.rosuda.REngine.REngine r;
    REXP result;
    String df="df";
    String y="reponceTime";
    String x="nodes"; 
    Rengine rengine = new Rengine (new String [] {"--vanilla"}, false, null);
    // Check if the session is working.
    if (!rengine.waitForR()) {
        return;
    }

    r=new JRIEngine(rengine);
    // load library to perform symbolic regression
    rengine.eval("library(rgp)");   

    rengine.eval(x+" <- c(3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0)");
    rengine.eval(y+" <- c(33205.8, 29279.24, 27775.28, 24074.12, 22360.44, 19737.6, 19374.88, 18794.12, 18687.88)");
    rengine.eval(df+" <- data.frame("+x+", "+y+")");

    String symbolic="s <- symbolicRegression("
            + y+" ~ "+ x+ ", data="+ df
            + ",functionSet=arithmeticFunctionSet, stopCondition=makeStepsStopCondition(30))";
//      + ",functionSet=fs, stopCondition=makeStepsStopCondition(2000))";

System.out.println("Executing: "+ symbolic);
    rengine.eval(symbolic);

    result=rengine.eval("s$bestFitness");
    System.out.println("bestFitness is "+result);

    rengine.eval("bm <- s$population[[which.min(s$fitnessValues)]]");
    result=rengine.eval("bm");
    System.out.println("bm is "+result);
    r.close();      

} }
```

and the result I get is:

```
Executing: s <- symbolicRegression(reponceTime~ nodes, data=df,functionSet=arithmeticFunctionSet, stopCondition=makeStepsStopCondition(30))
bestFitness is [REAL* (19040.339878315513)]
bm is [NULL]
```

Comment: Have you run your R code in R before trying it from java?

Comment: yes I did it..it works fine from R